# Either Data or Input box in one column in listview vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a listview and was able to bind the data to it from the database. Now my problem is, depending on the type of permit, there is one column either it is a data from the database or should be an input box. How do I dynamically change the listview accordingly?
For Example
[image: ListView Sample]

```
          <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
              <%# CheckNull(Eval("PERMIT_Date"))%>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          </td>
```

Below is my design code:

```
   asp:listview runat="server" ID="lsvPermits" 
       ItemPlaceholderID="itemApplication" DataKeyNames="PERMIT_TYPE_ID" 
       style="width:100%">
     <LayoutTemplate>
      <table class="ListView_Style" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border- 
             collapse:collapse">
        <tr class="ListView_Style ListView_HeaderStyle" >
           <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPurchase" Suffix="?"
                   Text="[Purchase?]"></asp:Label>                                    
           </th>
           <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPERMIT_TYPE_DESC" 
                    Text="[PERMIT TYPE DESCRIPTION]" >
               </asp:Label>
           </th>                                
           <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemApplication" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
         </table>
      </LayoutTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <tr runat="server" id="trItem" >
        <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
             <Asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbtnPermit" />                                                                                               
          <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
             <%# CheckNull(Eval("PERMIT_TYPE_DESC"))%>
          </td>
          <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
              <%# CheckNull(Eval("PERMIT_Date"))%>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
          </td>   
        </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr runat="server" ID="trMatchRow" >                           
        </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>
     <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table class="ListView_Style" cellspacing="0" align="left" rules="all" 
          border="1" style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
          <tr >
            <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
               <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPurchase" Suffix="?"
                    Text="[Purchase?]"></asp:Label>                                    
            </th>
            <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPERMIT_TYPE_DESC" 
                     Text="[PERMIT TYPE DESCRIPTION]" >
                </asp:Label>
            </th>           
          </tr>
          <tr id="MatchRow0">
            <td style= "text-align:center;" colspan="8" class="hideBorder">
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNoRecords" 
                     Text="[There are no records to display]" >
                </asp:Label>
             </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
     </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:listview>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, not all that great if a user enters a value wrong, and then can't change it?

But, ignoring the above issue, then the event you use for custom formatting in a gridview, listiew, repeater etc.?

You can as a general rule adopt the row data bound event. In that event you can format numbers, perhaps add color highlights to the whole row, or even a single column value. So, this event is quite much your "on format" row event in a sense. And even perhaps a column that is say a tax calculation based on other column values - again, the row data bound event is a great choice here.

So, we could either hide a control, and display a different one, but I think that the control "enabled" and "disabled" setting should work here.

I don't have your data, but let's take a simple listview, and have a date column in the lv, and if it has a value - we disable, and if not, then we allow entry of the value.

So, this looks to work:

```
<asp:ListView ID="LVHotels" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="">
            <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="HotelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="CityLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></td>
            <td><asp:Label ID="DescriptionLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>' /></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtBookingDate" runat="server" textmode="Date" >
                </asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" 
            class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:50%">
            <tr runat="server" style="">
                <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
                <th runat="server">LastName</th>
                <th runat="server" style="width: 200px">HotelName</th>
                <th runat="server">City</th>
                <th runat="server">Description</th>
                <th runat="server">Booking date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
            </tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdSave" runat="server" Text="Save changes"
    CssClass="btn btn-info" />
```

And our code to load is this:

```
Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName"
Dim rstData As DataTable

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
        Session("MyData") = rstData
    Else
        rstData = Session("MyData")
    End If
End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()

    rstData = MyRst(strSQL)

    LVHotels.DataSource = rstData
    LVHotels.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now our row data bound event, is this:

```
Protected Sub LVHotels_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemEventArgs) Handles LVHotels.ItemDataBound

    If e.Item.ItemType = ListViewItemType.DataItem Then

        Dim txtDate As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("txtBookingDate")
        Dim dRow As DataRowView = e.Item.DataItem

        If IsDBNull(dRow("BookingDate")) Then
            txtDate.Enabled = True
        Else
            txtDate.Text = CType(dRow("BookingDate"), Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            txtDate.Enabled = False
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

And now we see/have this:

[image]

So, when we edit 1 or 5 of them? And then hit save, note how they "disable" since when we save the data, we simple re-load the lv.

So, all we need is our save button.

That is this code:

```
Protected Sub cmdSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click

    For Each gRow As ListViewItem In LVHotels.Items
        Dim OneDataRow As DataRow = rstData.Rows(gRow.DataItemIndex)
        Dim txtBookDate As TextBox
        txtBookDate = gRow.FindControl("txtBookingDate")
        If txtBookDate.Text <> "" Then
            OneDataRow("BookingDate") = txtBookDate.Text
        End If
    Next

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL)
            Dim daU As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
            da.Update(rstData)
        End Using
    End Using

    LoadGrid()

End Sub
```